# Convert a float into a time format mm:ss

Tags: objective-c, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm searching a way with Objective-C to convert a float (audioPlayer.currentTime, which for example = 3.4592) into a time string with minutes and seconds (03:46)

I tried this:

```
static NSDateFormatter *date_formatter = nil;
if (date_formatter == nil) {
    date_formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [date_formatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];
}
NSDate *diff = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:audioPlayer.currentTime];
NSLog(@"%@", [date_formatter stringFromDate:diff]);
```

... but that's not working. The format is correct but I can't find a way to correctly initialize the "diff" date.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which are the units of audioPlayer.currentTime ? Minutes, seconds, milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert float in to seconds like this

```
    double d = CMTimeGetSeconds(__avPlayer.currentItem.duration);
```

Then its matter of converting that into NSString for presentation below method might help you

```
- (NSString *) printSecond:(NSInteger) seconds {

    if (seconds < 60) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:%02d",seconds];
    }

    if (seconds >= 60) {

        int minutes = floor(seconds/60);
        int rseconds = trunc(seconds - minutes * 60);

        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",minutes,rseconds];

    }

    return @"";

}
```