# How to show duration of video record in a textfield

Tags: objective-c, camera, avfoundation, media-player, assetslibrary

I am using AVFoundation to record and save video files to camera roll. But at the same time i wanna show the duration of these video in a simple text field.. Any ideas?

//i have seperated as 2 methods but still getting 0 seconds for stopping cam

```
- (IBAction)startCamera:(id)sender {

if (!recording)
{
    //----- START RECORDING -----
    NSLog(@"START RECORDING");
    recording = YES;


 //Create temporary URL to record to
    NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mov"];
    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:outputPath])
    {
    }
    //Start recording
    [MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];     

AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:outputURL options:nil];
    CMTime videoDuration = videoAsset.duration;
    float videoDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoDuration);

    NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:videoDurationSeconds];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];  //we can vary the date string. Ex: "mm:ss"
    NSString* result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Duration 1 of this after starting : %2@",result);
```

//stop camera method

```
-(void)stopCamera:(id)sender {

//----- STOP RECORDING -----
    NSLog(@"STOP RECORDING");
    recording = NO;
    [MovieFileOutput stopRecording];

//Create temporary URL to record to
    NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mov"];
    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:outputURL options:nil];
    CMTime videoDuration = videoAsset.duration;
    float videoDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoDuration);

    NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:videoDurationSeconds];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];  //we can vary the date string. Ex: "mm:ss"
    NSString* result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Duration 2 of this after stopping : %2@",result);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
CMTime videoDuration = videoAsset.duration;
float videoDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoDuration);

NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:videoDurationSeconds];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];  //you can vary the date string. Ex: "mm:ss"
NSString* result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

You need to link CoreMedia and AVFoundation framework in your project

Comment: okay thank you for your answer but when i use this i am always gettin 0 seconds.. :/ @sanjay

Comment: try this once try http://www.faqz.xyz/answer/how-to-get-the-time-duration-of-recorded-video-in-iphone-app

Comment: same answer with this :/

Comment: Upto the CMTime line its correct, but then to get seconds, use this : float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time);

Comment: Then you will need to use an NSDateFormatter to convert that into readable minutes/seconds.  Theres a few steps here.

Comment: as per  @LukeSmith  suggestion edited answer check once

Comment: thank you guys i am putting the codes after stop recording part but still getting 00.00.00..  @sanjay

Comment: I made some changes can you take a look please @LukeSmith

Comment: I made some changes can you take a look please now @sanjay

Comment: Hi there, once Ive got a float (or double) of seconds value, I use a method like the one described here to convert to a time string : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702538/convert-a-float-into-a-time-format-mmss

Comment: ..I also had trouble getting the NSDateFormatter to do what I wanted, even though I know it does do the job fine.

Comment: is there any way to add miliseconds as well?

Answer (score 0):

start a timer as you start the recording ...

```
- (IBAction)startCamera:(id)sender {

if (!recording)
{
      //----- START RECORDING -----
      NSLog(@"START RECORDING");
      recording = YES;

 _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(getCountInSec:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];


     //Create temporary URL to record to

else {
  //----- STOP RECORDING -----
NSLog(@"STOP RECORDING");
recording = NO;

if ([_timer isValid]) {
    [_timer invalidate];
}
_timer = nil;
[MovieFileOutput stopRecording];

  }
 }
```

// here is timer methods ..

```
-(void)getCountInSec
 {   
  // set a global variable of int type . every time increment by one & manage as you need (Sec ,min or hours). 

     yourlbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormate@"%ld",yourVarable];

}
```

Hope it help you .

Comment: can you check it again?